# The Dirac delta function

Tags: hilbert-spaces, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

I am to prove that $\delta(ax) =\frac{\delta(x)}{|a|} $

The following is my reasoning:

I begin with, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x') f(x') dx'=f(0) \tag{1} $$ Where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function and where $f$ is a single variable function. I make the substitution $x'=|a|x$ to get, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(ax) f(|a|x) |a|d(x)\tag{2}$$
Since $\delta$ is an even function. Eqs. (1) and (2) give the same result. So, on equating them we see, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x')  dx'=|a| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(ax) d(x)\tag{3}$$ Where $f(x')$and $ f(|a|x)$ are treated as constants and are equal in an infinitesimal interval $(-\epsilon/a, \epsilon/a) $ about zero. Here, $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal. Eq.(3) can be re-written as $$\int_{-\epsilon/a}^{\epsilon/a} \frac{\delta(x')}{|a|} dx'=\int_{-\epsilon/a}^{\epsilon/a} \delta(ax) d(x)$$
The Delta function is zero everywhere else. Eq.(5) implies that $\delta(x) =\frac{\delta(x)}{|a|} $. This concludes the proof.

I would like to know if there are any flaws in reasoning.

Comment: Mathematicians would have easier to follow if you had used the normal notation for function application $f(x)$ instead of $\langle x | f \rangle$. When you also have $|a|$ inside those brackets it gets really confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first answer this question physics-style and then reanswer this rigorously for any math students who may happen to see this.

**Physics Answer**

The basic conceptual problem is that the *only* way to prove an equality of generalised functions $\phi$ and $\psi$ is to show that
$$
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\,f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(x)\,f(x)\,dx
$$
for *all* suitable ordinary functions $f$—anything else is completely unreliable. In this case, this would mean showing that
$$
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(ax)\,f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty} \frac{1}{\lvert a \rvert}\delta(x)\,f(x)\,dx
$$
for all suitable ordinary functions $f$.

So, we need to proceed more carefully. Fix $a \neq 0$, and let $f$ be any suitable ordinary function. Let $x^\prime = ax$. Since $f(x) = f(a^{-1}x^\prime)$, so that 
$$
 f(x)\rvert_{x = 0} = f(0) = f(a^{-1}0) = f(a^{-1}x^\prime)\vert_{x^\prime=0},
$$
it follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)\,f(x)\,dx
&= f(0)\\
&= f(a^{-1}0)\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x^\prime) f(a^{-1}x^\prime)\,dx^\prime\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(ax)\,f(x)\lvert a \rvert dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\lvert a \rvert \delta(ax) \right) f(x) \, dx;
\end{align}
$$
since $f$ was arbitary, you can conclude that
$$
 \delta(x) = \lvert a \rvert \delta(ax),
$$
which gives you what you want.

**Mathematics Answer**

Recall that the Dirac delta is the distribution (generalised function) $\delta \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}) := C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})^\prime$ defined by
$$
 \forall f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}), \quad \delta(f) := f(0).
$$
For any $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, define a linear transformation $S_a : C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \to C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ by
$$
 \forall f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}), \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad (S_a f)(x) := f(ax).
$$
For any $a \neq 0$, one can use the change of coordinates $x^\prime = ax$ to show that for all $f,g \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$,
$$
\begin{align}
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty (S_a f)(x)\, g(x)\,dx 
&= \int_{-\infty} f(ax)\,g(x)\,dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x^\prime) g(a^{-1}x^\prime)\frac{1}{\lvert a \rvert}dx^\prime\\
&= \int_{-\infty} f(x) \left(\frac{1}{\lvert a \rvert}S_{a^{-1}}g\right)(x) \,dx,
\end{align}
$$
i.e., that $S_a^\ast = \lvert a \rvert^{-1} S_{a^{-1}}$ with respect to the $L^2$ inner product on $\mathbb{R}$, so, by duality, we're obliged to *define* $S_a\delta$ (i.e., $\delta(ax)$) to be the distribution
$$
 S_a\delta := \delta \circ \frac{1}{\lvert a \rvert}S_{a^{-1}} \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}).
$$
But now, for any $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$,
$$
 (S_a\delta)(f) 
= \delta\left(\frac{1}{\lvert a \rvert}S_{a^{-1}}f\right)
= \left(\frac{1}{\lvert a \rvert}S_{a^{-1}}f\right)(0)
= \frac{1}{\lvert a \rvert}f(a^{-1}0)
= \frac{1}{\lvert a \rvert}f(0)
= \left(\frac{1}{\lvert a \rvert}\delta\right)(f),
$$
so that, indeed,
$$
 S_a\delta = \frac{1}{\lvert a \rvert}\delta,
$$
which is the rigorous statement of the identity $\delta(ax) = \frac{1}{\lvert a \rvert}\delta(x)$.

Comment: I realized the fatal flaw. I corrected it.

Comment: My edits came in the moment you posted. I'll go through your answer now.

Comment: There's a more fundamental conceptual issue---please see the comments in the edited answer about equality of generalised functions.

Comment: This is an excellent answer(I could follow the physics answer). Clears it for me. +1